# Writing a demo for snake game

Tags: java

I've written a snake game in Java. What I also want to do is to create a demo for that (so snake would play by itself). I've written a simple demo, but snake dies pretty fast. So, is there any algorithms or something for that kind of problem? I believe it is a little bit similar to chess game problem? **I want that snake would be alive as long as possible**. Thank you.

Comment: Easy solution = Slow the snake down!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Google-sponsored [AI Challenge](http://aichallenge.org/) ran a "Tron" game in 2010. You might get some good ideas from searching for solutions to that challenge.

If you just want a very simple strategy that makes a reasonable demo then you might try something like the following:

- Never make a move that causes you to crash unless you have no other option
- If your next move forces you to choose between two or more distinct (unconnected) spaces, always move into the larger of the two spaces. This will stop your snake from getting trapped too easily.
- If you are moving along a wall, keep moving along the wall 98% of the time, following it around to the left or right as needed. This will help your snake look reasonably intelligent, and also conserve space in the playfield.
- Otherwise move ahead 90% of the time, turn left and right randomly 5% of the time each (this will make your demo less boring).

Apart from that, I don't think a Chess-style AI approach (with a move search tree) would work very well. You wouldn't be able to easily search enough moves in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the answer you are looking for, but I post it because I would genuinely like to see you explore this algorithm further, modifying it until you find yourself with a pretty reasonable AI:

The simplest algorithm to solve this problem is the "go around the edge, and then squiggle downward" approach. Basically, you start out with a snake, get it so it is moving west, then hug the west wall, then the ceiling. Then you traverse over every possible square like a slinky until you get to the bottom, go west, and start all over again.

If you try, you can turn this into a really excellent AI :D

Answer (score 1):

Without doing the work for you, I can tell you that the best way to start approaching a problem like this is to think about what the snake should do to survive as long as possible.  What 'rules of thumb' should the snake follow in order to stay alive.  For starters the snake should probably turn before it hits an obstruction, and towards a direction where it won't be boxed in.  So, you can program the snake to turn when it is within one space of it's tail (or wall) and towards a direction with the greatest distance between it and other obstructions.  Also, snake I believe is a game in which the computer can play perfectly and in your demo you may not want that so you can always throw in some randomness just to spice things up if things get too same-y.